# Inorder tree traversal with minimal parentheses

Tags: python, expression-trees, parentheses, infix-notation

My question is how to print the expression tree in the infix notation with minimal parentheses in python. The problem is that my output differs from the desired output for examples below.

Input: 1 2 3 + -, output: (1-(2+3)), desired output: 1-(2+3).
Input: 1 2 3 4 5 6 + * + * +, output: 1+(2* 3+(4* (5+6))), desired output: 1+2*(3+4*(5+6)).

```
class Sav:
    
    def __init__(self , value):
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

def operator(c):
    if (c == '+' or c == '-' or c == '*' or c == '/'):
        return True
    else:
        return False

def priority(g):
    if (g == '+'):
        return 0
    elif (g == '-'):
        return 1
    elif (g == '*'):
        return 2
    elif (g == '/'):
        return 3
    else:
        return -1

def tree(p):
    stack = []
    for char in range(len(p)):
        if not operator(p[char]):
            t = Sav(p[char])
            stack.append(t)
        else:
            t = Sav(p[char])
            t1 = stack.pop()
            t2 = stack.pop()
            t.right = t1
            t.left = t2
            stack.append(t)
    t = stack.pop()
    return t


def infix(t):
    if t != None:
        if t.left == None and t.right == None:
            print(t.value, end='')
    else:
        if priority(t.value) > priority(t.right.value):
            print('(', end='')   
            infix(t.left)
            print(t.value, end='')
            infix(t.right)
            print(')', end='')   
        else:
            infix(t.left)
            print(t.value, end='')
            infix(t.right) 

postfix = []
postfix = input().split()
r = tree(postfix)
infix(r)
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a question here.

Comment: The question is how to implement minimal parentheses.

Comment: Your code isn’t runnable - please correct the syntax and make it a [mre] including all needed imports. Also you need to include in the code some sample input (NOT input expected from the user at runtime), the expected/desired output and the actual output produced by the code in the question.

Comment: Is there a problem with the code you posted? If not then you would not ask a question here, but if there is then you need to describe the problem - see [mcve].